# Excel Run-time error '91'

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel file with a codeblock in Module 1.
This codeblock is working without problems.
When i open this .xlsm file and open the Visual Basic editor and open the Module (in this case Module 1) and don't make any changes there or only change a word in a comment line, but save the Module after that and close the Excel file, something goes wrong.
When I open the file the next time, I get a error message:

Run-time error '91'
Object variable or With block variable not set

How can that be, when i didn't make any changes to the Module there?

Just to make it more understandable, here is my script in Module 1:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()

'Sub ImportCSVs()
'Import all CSV files from a folder into separate sheets

Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook

Set wbMST = ActiveWorkbook

'Update the path to your CSV files below. Add your-username and your-folder
'Don't remove the the final \ from the file path

fPath = "C:\xampp\htdocs\csv\excel\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")

Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)
    ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)

    fCSV = Dir
Loop

Set wbCSV = Nothing

'Remove blank sheets, delete the first row from each sheet, zoom out and format as table

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells) <> 0 Then

    'ws.Rows(1).Delete
    ws.Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    ws.UsedRange.Select
        'ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ActiveSheet.UsedRange, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
        'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"
        Selection.Columns.AutoFit

  End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells) = 0 Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

Next ws

'End
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'open entry.xlsm after import all data
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\USER\Documents\entry.xlsm")

'minimize the data sheet
Windows("data.xlsm").Visible = False

'Dim wbkMain, wbk_A
'Set wbMain = ThisWorkbook
'Set wbk_A = Workbooks("entry.xlsm")
'Set wbk_A = ActiveWorkbook

End Sub
```

When I saved the Macro after changing nothing, the line

```
ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)
```

is highlited yello in the debugger...

I am not very experienced in Macro programming and I have no idea, what's going on there.

Thanks for any help

Comment: put a breakpoint at `ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)` and debug. Add `wbMST` to watch window and validate the value.